# Page wrongly displayed when cache plugin activated

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I tried both WP Rocket and WP Total cache, and when activating page caching, my pages look like this: http://www.goldnord.fr/

So all the pictures, animations, structure is gone.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Disable `minify` option in your settings. Also do you really have a CDN setup properly. You can try 2 things. 1. Disable CDN and try. 2. Disable `minify` CSS and JS files.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Disable CDN. It must work then. You haven't setup CDN cname properly.